# Does the program stop excuting once it returns something?

Tags: java

```
public int max1020(int a, int b) {
  // First make it so the bigger value is in a
  if (b > a) {
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
  }

  // Knowing a is bigger, just check a first
  if (a >= 10 && a <= 20) return a;
  if (b >= 10 && b <= 20) return b;
  return 0;
}
```

so if both a and b are within the range [10,20], would it just return a, and stop excuting  the next two lines of code?

Comment: The method returns at a return (so the method stops executing). The program is usually more than one method.

Comment: public int max1020(int a, int b) , does this line mean that the method will return a integer, and max1020 is the name of the method, and int a and int b are the inputs? oftentimes I see public static void  something something, does it mean that it returns a "void"? although I don't know what void is

Comment: void means you will not get any return value. The value returned is void i.e nothing and cannot be collected as its void.

Comment: As it seems you're learning programming, you *really* should read a book, or a website before asking here.

Comment: An excellent resource to get started is the official [Oracle Java Tutorial chapter on methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) - your questions are covered there (and in the following chapters - specifically [Returning a Value from a Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html))

Comment: i am learning programming, and i just got stated taking an OOP class in Java with 0 preceding coding experience, i read a book called intro to java, but it's too long and i forget what i read regularly.

Answer (score 1):

> so if both a and b are within the range [10,20], would it just return a, and stop executing the next two lines of code?

It first checks a, if it matches the first condition then the function is returned with the value of a. The next two lines of code will not be executed as the function has returned.

> Does the program stop executing once it returns something?

No, the value is not returned by the whole program it is just returned by the particular function. Let me give you an example.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int result;

    // The method max1020 returns the value of 'a' here
    result = max1020(11,14);
    System.out.println(result);

    // The method max1020 returns the value of 'b' here
    result = max1020(31,11);
    System.out.println(result);

    // The method max1020 returns the value of '0' here
    result = max1020(50,60);
    System.out.println(result);
}

private static int max1020(int a, int b) {
    // First make it so the bigger value is in a
    if (b > a) {
        int temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }

    // Knowing a is bigger, just check a first
    if (a >= 10 && a <= 20) return a;
    if (b >= 10 && b <= 20) return b;
    return 0;
}
```

}

The return keyword just gets you out of the function you are in, it does not get you out of your whole program. When you call the max1020() for the first time it returns a. See it returns the value of a but the program will still execute the other lines. It will print the value of the variable result then it'll again call the max1020() on another pair of values.

Answer (score 0):

If both a and b are within the range [10,20] it will always return a.
You are correct, once a return statement is reached, it will not execute any further code.

Comment: That was not the question

Comment: This can be a comment

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in the assumption that the program checks if a is withing the range, and given that the result of the evaluation is true it will return the value bond to variable a. 
In Java the keyword **return** means that the program will return the value associated with it and stops further execution.

As for your question about the void method. In Java and many other languages you have something called "[state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_(computer_science))" which means that there exists some values outside of the current scope of execution, e.g in pseudocode

```
   int a = 0
     public void inc (){
     a++
}
```

Method inc does not take any arguments (it has an arity of 0) but increments the variable a that is defined outside the scope of the function it self. Any method that has other return type than void returns the defined type.

I hope that my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing *method return* and *program exit* (which can also be called "*program return code*").

In a method, whenever the line `return` is reached, the method stops right there and will not execute further instructions.

When that method is the `main` method, it also is the entry-point of the program. Therefore, when the `main` calls `return`, the program will effectively stop, returning code `0` (which means "success").

In Java, you can also stop a *program* execution by calling [`System.exit(ret)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit(int)). *In that particular case*, the JVM process (which is "your program") will stop executing further instructions, *even if `return` is not explicitly called* (though some IDE will give you errors or warnings). The return code (seen by the caller process) will be the one you specified with `ret`.